# Postgresql how to update a column if a string has a word in it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

table A that has a postcode column with one postcode each row (example row: E1 8NF)

table B that has a postcode column with multiple postcodes separated by a comma (example row: E1 8NF, E1 8NG, E1 8NJ)

If the postcode from table A exists in table B, I want to give it a 1

How to do this in postgresql? My query so far

```
UPDATE tablea
set pcd = 1 where tablea.postcode exists in tableb.postcode ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the comma separated list into an array, then use that in a sub-select:

```
update tablea a
    set pcd = 1
where exists (select *
              from tableb b
              where a.postcode = any(string_to_array(b.postcodes, ','))
              );
```

If the values are stored with spaces between the commas, you would need to apply a `trim()` which probably is easier with a join in the update:

```
update tablea a
    set pcd = 1
from (
   select trim(x.pc) as pc
   from tableb b, 
        unnest(string_to_array(b.postcodes)) as x(px)
) t
where a.postcode = t.pc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing lists in a comma separated field is a really bad idea.  It is even worse in a database such as Postgres that has very reasonable alternatives -- such as arrays and JSON fields.  But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad decisions.

One method is:

```
update tablea a
    set pcd = 1
    where exists (select 1
                  from tableb b
                  where ',' || a.postcode || ',' like ',' || replace(b.postcodes, ', ', ',') || ','
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
UPDATE tablea set pcd = 1 where postcode in (select b.postcode from tableb);
```